# Error message "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET CORE app with a few projects inside and the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY src/Mbv.Vans.Core/Mbv.Vans.Core.csproj Mbv.Vans.Core/
COPY src/Mbv.Vans.Common/Mbv.Vans.Common.csproj Mbv.Vans.Common/
COPY src/Mbv.Vans.Api/Mbv.Vans.Api.csproj Mbv.Vans.Api/

RUN dotnet restore Mbv.Vans.Api/Mbv.Vans.Api.csproj
COPY . .
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Mbv.Vans.Api/Mbv.Vans.Api.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Mbv.Vans.Api.dll"]
```

On line `RUN dotnet publish Mbv.Vans.Api/Mbv.Vans.Api.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app` When it tries to build the project, it fails with error:

> "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
     <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
     <NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>
     <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I searched a lot of questions regarding this issue and divide it into the following resolutions:

1. `COPY . .` is not fixing this issue
2. I have only one `static void main`
3. `<GenereteProgramFile> false` doesn't help.

Could someone can help me to beat this awfull issue?

Comment: What is your project structure? Share us it and where did you run the docker command? For this error, it is usually cased by that there is no `Program.cs` in the folder.

Comment: It'd be good to know more details on this.  Do you have source files available publicly that can repro the issue?  What project is your Main method located in?  Have you tried to reproduce the issue outside the context of Docker (e.g. copy the set of folders you're copying in your Dockerfile to a separate folder on your machine and try building from that new location)?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816916/could-not-find-xxx-program-specified-for-main-method-when-building-dotnet-app/55851522#55851522 maybe that will work

Answer (score 1):

So, I ran across this same issue and drove me insane. The solution here is to skip the build and go right to a publish.

I was helped by looking at this particular sample: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile.alpine-x64

As you can see in there, there is no build occurring. There is a restore, and then a publish. Why no build? I don't know. I'm investigating, but I'm happy it worked for me at least. Let me know how it goes.

Edited for additional info:

Here is the original non-working Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["mercurynorth_netcore/mercurynorth_netcore.csproj", "mercurynorth_netcore/"]
RUN dotnet restore "mercurynorth_netcore/mercurynorth_netcore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/mercurynorth_netcore"
RUN dotnet build "mercurynorth_netcore.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "mercurynorth_netcore.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mercurynorth_netcore.dll"]
```

...and here the the newly working Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app


# Lets do a restore of the NuGet packages, and then restore the app in a container.
COPY mercurynorth_netcore.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore "mercurynorth_netcore.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "mercurynorth_netcore.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mercurynorth_netcore.dll"]
```

As you can see, what I generally did was remove the line:

```
RUN dotnet build "mercurynorth_netcore.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

...as well as do some clean-up.

The general take-away is that running the build command on my dev machine(s) will work fine, but as part of building the container, it will fail.

Comment: Please add relevant parts from your link here.

Comment: There is no build because 'RUN dotnet publish' does build process. You can specify parameters to enable or disable.

Comment: CaseyK - can you share what your Dockerfile looked like when it wasn't working and what changes you made to get it to work?  As AlexZholob says, running the build command should be unnecessary in theory because publish is implicitly doing that.

Comment: Thanks for this - I had exactly the same issue, it seems to be related to setting the `-o` value, if you don't specify it then `build` works but if you use it then it doesn't for some reason but publish does.