# Could not find 'xxx.Program' specified for Main method when building dotnet app in Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am having issues when building a dotnet core application inside a docker container. I am using dotnet core 2.2.

The setting for the project are:
Output: Console App
Startup Project: Web.Project

When running the command below inside the container:

```
RUN dotnet build "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

I get the error below:

```
Could not find 'Web.Program' specified for Main method [/src/Web/Web.csproj]
```

If the project is just an assembly (dll) everything works fine but I'm unable to run the web app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803270/error-message-program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-e/55679134.  This is being tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1056.  It'd be great if you could provide more details on your project, including a link to the code if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to remove the following line from my csproj file:

```
<OutputType>EXE</OutputType>
```

It seems like visual studio 2107 adds that tag when changing the output type. Once I removed that, I was able to build and publish inside a Docker Container and Windows.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have a `<StartupObject>` tag in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was folder with repository `/home/ubuntu/project` was the same folder as i targeted to build `dotnet build -C Release --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64` --output /home/ubuntu/project`.

Solution was to change it `dotnet build -C Release --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64` --output /home/ubuntu/project_build`

Answer (score 0):

Using my case, since I changed the name of the namespace and solution.

- I  edited the .csproj
- at every tag where I found the old name, I replaced it with the new one,
- Cleaned build, build and the error went away